# Single value for a quaternion

Tags: java, matlab, quaternions

Quaternions are of the form `q = w + x*i + y*j + z*k` where `i`, `j` & `k` are the vectors which represent dimensions and `w` is the scalar. Given 4 values that represent the `w`, `x`, `y`, `z` components, I need to find the value of `q`.

I have looked through many MATLAB functions but most of them deal with quaternion multiplication, normalization etc. Can anyone please tell me how I can find a single value `q` for a given quaternion?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried in Java as this appears to be more of a Maths question than how to program in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(w,x,y,z) is the value of the quaternion.

When you say a single value for q - do you mean the norm of the quaternion? In this case the norm is:

Math.sqrt(w*w+x*x+y*y+z*z).

Comment: I am not very well-versed with the concept of quaternions.  Would norm act as a good representation of the four values? I would need to compare this value with the norms of other quaternions. Can you please tell me if this seems sensible?